# Actions after saving a state

Tags: modal-windows

I am building an application for a scanner.

Part of the application is a profile management section where a user can change settings for profiles. The user can change one profile at a time and return to the application or s/he can change many profiles in the same session.

In other words OnSave the user will either want to return to the application main screen or the modal containing the profiles.

How do I control this?

Idea

[image]

Idea

[image]

Which option is better? Is there another way?

Comment: How much effort is it to go to the main screen and then go to the profile management section? If it's one step, then I wouldn't make it more complicated by returning to the main screen.

Comment: it would be an extra click

Answer (score 2):

[image]

First, Instead of using OK use the word again save for "SAVE" - delete "DELETE"  because it is more explicit for users. It looks like that profile selection and saving profile flow *affect* the real functionality and/or procedure  - in this case scanning procedure.

When profile is saved; the window can be turned to main functionality - with **selected** state of what saved - to continue the intended function(SCAN).

For that reason the first prompt window is easier to understand but instead of doing it in a third modal layer; it can be placed on the same window.

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems use something like this:

[Apply] [Done] [Cancel]

- [Apply] - Applies changes but stays in the modal.
- [Done] - Applies changes and closes the modal.
- [Cancel] - Closes the modal without saving changes.